# Submitting a form from iPhone to PHP

Tags: javascript, ios, ajax, forms, post

Surely I'm missing something simple... Below is a simple form I am trying to submit to a PHP script. It runs fine on PC and Mac But not in Safari on ipad, iphone, etc. I'm guessing there is a mobile component I am missing?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

$('form').submit(function(){
    var postData = $(this).serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: postData,
        url: "http://www.norwichandyork.com/pocketleads/utilities/accounts.php",
        success: function(data){
            console.log(data);
            alert('Your comment was successfully added');
        },
        error: function(){
            console.log(data);
            alert('There was an error adding your comment');
        }
    });

    return false;
});
</script>
</head>
<body>


<form method="post" action="http://www.norwichandyork.com/pocketleads/utilities/accounts.php">
    <label for="email">
        <b>Email</b>
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email">
    </label>

    <label for="fname">
        <b>fname</b>
        <input type="text" id="fname" name="fname">
    </label>

    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

I've re-posted my complete code and left the action url so that anyone can easily try it. Thanks in advance for all your help. :)

Comment: You did include jquery somewhere, right?

Comment: Even though the jQuery include is nowhere in the code posted, I don't see how it would work fine on PC/Mac without.

Comment: Yes, <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.min.js"></script> is at the top of my code. Adding the action (and fixing the method to read method="post") had no effect. Still sucking pond water here ):

Answer (score 1):

Solved! Not sure if its an Xcode or PhoneGap thing but you must whitelist every domain you access from your app. While I did have my domain whitelisted, it still didn't work. I discovered this while checking my compile error log. I found this: http://www.prosoxi.com/2011/10/08/xcode-phonegap-white-list-rejection/ and by adding *.mydomain.com to the whitelist, all works fine now. Thanks all for your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

instead of

```
<script language="JavaScript">
```

Answer (score 0):

> `<form action="post">`

The `action` attribute of the `form` element specifies where the data should be sent. Unless your PHP script is called `post` I think you should change `action` to `method` and include the real action.

> `<script language="JavaScript">`

Also, you shouldn't specify the `language` attribute of the `script` element (that hasn't been used for ages), but prior to HTML5 you should use the `type` attribute and for JS its value should be `text/javascript`. Since HTML5 all `script` elements are assumed to be JavaScript unless specified otherwise.

I wrote all this and then realized you were hijaxing the form anyway so the `action`/`method` thing doesn't really matter. It may be helpful anyway tho so I'll leave the answer.

Comment: setting the form action shouldn't matter, because of it being sent over ajax

Comment: Yes, that's why I wrote the last paragraph. I definitely think it's better to work with progressive enhancement though and such a simple thing as setting the form action and using that in your script (rather than hard coding it) would make it work on devices with JS disabled as well.